# Bleak House language

Tags: archaicisms, charles-dickens

I've been reading Bleak House, and I came across this sentence:

> Still the woman follows, crying, "Stop him, sir, pray stop him!" Allan, not knowing **but** that he has just robbed her of her money, follows in chase and runs so hard that he runs the boy down a dozen times...

What does but in this sentence mean?

And here is another, also from Bleak House:

> "And I **would that** you could take your leave, and we could all take our leave, Mr. Vholes."

I've never met such expression before. Is it an archaic variant of 'I would rather you'?

Comment: "I would that" = "I wish that".  This is archaic language, and neither expression is in common use these days.

Comment: *not knowing **but** that X* is a slightly roundabout (and nowadays, "quaint, antiquated") way of saying *not knowing **anything except** X* (or *knowing **nothing but** X*).

Comment: It might help to know that *would* is related to *will*, as in desire (why they call it a "last **will** and testament"). So "I would that you leave" is saying, as TrevorD stated, "It is my will that you leave" in a slightly different way. And in a convoluted way, yes, it's related to I would rather: "it is my will that rather than that, this."